# Why the Broker CPU's consume is 0.3 with a publisher with qos=2

Tags: mqtt, cpu-usage, mosquitto

I'm making some measurement on the CPU usage of the broker, in my topology i've got:

- 20 subscriber
- 1 publisher
- 1 controller, 1 access point, 1 broker.
- loss=30% on the ap-----broker link.

[image: Broker Cpu Usage with a loss of 30%, 1 publisher and 20 subscribers]

My question is:

How is even possible that the same publisher, seems to be more challenging for the broker with a qos=0 as the number of messages increases?

Instead

Why the cpu stays on the 0.3% with the same publisher, publishing with qos=2?
(I expected that with qos2 there would be more control messages and that the cpu where more stressed)

Comment: Also you've not included any data on what the message throughput is, so it is impossible to know if the brokers are behaving equally.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because at QOS2 the broker is spending more time waiting on the the network (for the 30% missing messages) than processing messages.

But the only way to be sure will be to actually profile the broker.